# Extracting pair of values from matrix using python

Tags: python

I have matrix as follows..

```
           31348   439352   6077    4619722    60825
31348      1        0.304   0.126    0.12      0.162
439352     0.304    1       0.101    0.095     0.316
6077       0.126    0.101   1        0.473     0.219
4619722    0.12     0.095   0.473    1         0.256
60825      0.162    0.316   0.219    0.256     1
```

Now i have to write python script to extract pairs which are having >0.2
the result should be as follows

```
439352, 31348  0.304
60825, 439352  0.316

.....
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this..

Thanks in advance

NI

Comment: If you post what you have tried so far you will be more likely to get help, and before anyone could possibly help with this we would need to know how your matrix is represented in Python.  Is your data in a file or is it stored as a list of lists, nested dictionaries etc.

Comment: This question is difficult to understand. Which pairs do you refer? Could you give the exact result you are expecting from the given matrix?.

Comment: My data is in .csv file my question how to extract pair of values from  x and y column which are having value > 0.2 for example from x column 31348 and y column 439352 is 0.304

Comment: Also I couldn't help but notice that your matrix is jagged (ie: the first row has less columns than the other ones). Is that just a copy and paste error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist = []

with open('test.csv') as f:
    keys = f.readline()
    keys = keys.split()

    for line in f:
        a = line.split()
        mylist.append(a[1:])

for idx1, item in enumerate(mylist):
    for idx2, number in enumerate(item):
        if float(number) > 0.2:
            print "%7s, %7s  --> %7s" %(keys[idx1], keys[idx2], number)
```

Produces:

```
  31348,   31348  -->       1
  31348,  439352  -->   0.304
 439352,   31348  -->   0.304
 439352,  439352  -->       1
 439352,   60825  -->   0.316
   6077,    6077  -->       1
   6077, 4619722  -->   0.473
   6077,   60825  -->   0.219
4619722,    6077  -->   0.473
4619722, 4619722  -->       1
4619722,   60825  -->   0.256
  60825,  439352  -->   0.316
  60825,    6077  -->   0.219
  60825, 4619722  -->   0.256
  60825,   60825  -->       1
```

This code suposes x and y indexes of the matrix are the same (as in your example). Otherwise you need to prepare two different keys lists.

**Note:** My test.csv file is just a text file where I copy-pasted your matrix (so actually it is not a .csv file). If you have comma separated values you should modify the split methods accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for help when i execute this script it is not giving any result or error..Not getting what is the reason